# edit datagridview cell to acept decimals number with dot separator

Tags: vb.net, edit, keyboard-events, decimalformat, datagridviewtextboxcell

I want to edit a datagridview cell to be able to write decimals numbers but with only a dot for decimals separator, BUT if the user try to write a dot as a separator, I want to change the dot for a comma in the textbox cell.

For example, if I want to write in the datagridview cell the number 45.6 (it is usual in my country to write this number like 45,6 or 45.6 ) the system should do:

1st step: User writes 4, and in the dgv cell appears a 4

2nd step: User writes 5, and in the dgv cell we have a 45

3rd step: User Writes '.' but before it is printed in the cell, the system change it for a ',' and in the cell we have 45,

4th step: User tries to write another '.' (or another ','), but the systems control it and doesn't write anything in the cell. We still have 45,

5th step: User writes '5', and in the cell we finally have a 45,6

I have tried to use the EditingControlShowing to get the textbox in the dgv:

```
Private Sub dgv_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox AndAlso dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
            Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            AddHandler textBox.KeyPress, AddressOf DataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress
            AddHandler textBox.KeyDown, AddressOf DataGridViewCell_KeyDown
        End If
    End Sub
```

The KeyPress event to change dot for comma

```
Private Sub DataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If e.KeyChar = "."c Then
            e.KeyChar = ","c
        End If
    End Sub
```

And the KeyDown event to control the format of the input string

```
Private Sub DataGridViewCell_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim nonNumberEntered As Boolean = False

    ' Checking keys to write decimal numbers: numbers, comma and delete key for corrections...
    If e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 OrElse e.KeyCode > Keys.D9 Then
        If e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 OrElse e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9 Then
            If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back Then
                If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Oemcomma Then
                    nonNumberEntered = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Dim currentTextBox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim currentText As String = currentTextBox.Text

    ' Check if the entered text matches the regular expression
    Dim inputRegex As New Regex("^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$")
    Dim isValidInput As Boolean = inputRegex.IsMatch(currentText)

    If Not isValidInput Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
    End If

    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I could solve it using Double.TryParse to the input string, but i don't want to give an error message to the user and asking him to write a number in a correct format, I really want not to let him to write wrong strings directly.

I have also tried other events (CellValidating, TextChanged...) but not succesfully. Even ChatGPT couldn't help me (probably my fault explaining my needs).

Maybe can any human ^^ help me with this? (VB or C# is ok) Thanks for your time!

Comment: I haven't got time to go into detail now but you should start by handling the `EditingControlShowing` event of the grid. That will provide access to the `Textbox` control used for editing. You can then handle its `KeyPress` event to detect and replace the appropriate character. Handle `EndEdit` toy remove the event handler. You can configure the column itself to format the data whatever way you want.